# Why is deja backup / duplicity so fast?

Tags: deja-dup, duplicity

I compared Deja backup/duplicity to Time Machine on similar hardware and Deja/duplicity is at least an order of magnitude faster. On same hardware an 100 MB incremental backup on Time Machine required the same time as 14 GB full backup in duplicity. Incremental backups in duplicity are lightning fast.

How does duplicity recognize changed files so fast in order to perform incremental backups?